# apply std::vector<T> functions to class derived from std::vector

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, stdvector

If a class derives from a vector, how can you preform (templated) vector functions on it?

For example the following code will not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Batch:public vector<int>{};

template<class T>
vector<vector<T> > interleave(vector<T> v, unsigned l){
    vector<vector<T> > r(l);
    int i=0;
    for(const  &t:v) r[(i++)%l].push_back(t);
    return r;
}

template<class T>
vector<T> flatten(vector< vector<T> > w){
    vector<T> r;
    for(const vector<T> &v:w)
        r.insert(r.end(),v.begin(),v.end());
    return r;
}

int main(){
    Batch         a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    vector<Batch> b = interleave(a,3);
    Batch         c = flatten(b);
    for(auto d:c) cout<<d<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
}
```

But it will compile if `class Batch:public vector<int>{};` is changed to `typedef vector<int> Batch;` to produce the desired output: `0 3 6 9 1 4 7 10 2 5 8 11`

Comment: Public inheritance from a vector is a bad idea.

Comment: Consider achieving what you want through [composition instead of inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  You're gonna hit a lot of headaches trying to simply pass data through to your vector base.

Comment: @SamCristall I've tried composition. It makes the code ugly, since I need to make a lot of special cases for templated functions.

Comment: @chris Could you elaborate why?

Comment: @DouwevanGijn, For starters, it simply wasn't designed for this. It has no virtual destructor. On an unrelated note, you have object slicing.

Comment: @chris Inheritance without virtual destructors has many applications, namely whenever runtime polymorphism isn't needed. Since C++11 adds inheriting constructors there's no reason not to inherit from `vector`, and this was a major motivation for that language feature.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, That's interesting to bring up. I'll read more into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function overload resolution will map an argument class type to the template it specializes, or to a base class, but not to the template specialized by a base class.

You can make a function that does both by using SFINAE, although it's a bit tricky. I'll do this in C++11 here but it doesn't inherently require any new language features.

```
template< template< typename ... > class a, template< typename ... > class b >
struct is_same_template : std::false_type {};

template< template< typename ... > class a >
struct is_same_template< a, a > : std::true_type {};

template< typename t >
typename std::enable_if< is_same_template< t::template vector, std::vector >::value,
    std::vector< t > >::type
interleave( t const & v, unsigned l ) {
```

Rather than looking for inheritance per se, this checks a class for a member template `vector` that is identical to `std::vector`. Since there is (currently) no way to alias one template-name to another such that they appear identical, this can never return a false positive, and could only return a false negative if you actually had a member named `vector` in your derived class.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in the comments, it's generally recommended not to inherit from the standard library containers. The usual rule is "prefer composition to inheritance", that is, give your class a `std::vector<T>` member instead of subclassing it.

Anyway, the problem you're facing is that you're trying to pass a `vector<Batch>` as a `vector<vector<T>>`. Since a `Batch` *is a* `vector<int>`, it might be reasonable to think that a `vector<Batch>` *is a* `vector<vector<int>>` too, but this is not the way C++ works -- [this question on Stroustrup's FAQ page](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#conversion) for a good explanation of why.

The easiest way around this would be to just say `Batch` when you mean `Batch`, as in

```
vector<Batch> interleave(const Batch& v, unsigned l);
Batch flatten(const vector<Batch>& w);
```

although of course you might prefer Potatoswatter's clever SFINAE solution to maintain generality.